# Why am I getting an extra keyword in my ElasticSearch Search results

Tags: elasticsearch

For reasons of not being able to move off it I am stuck with ElasticSearch version 6.8.6

I want to find the count of how many documents belong to a particular category.

So I have an aggregations query

I have a mapping for an array of values

```
"categoryValues":{"type":"keyword"}
```

I have a query

```
 {
    "_source": {
        "excludes": ["content", "categoryValues", "categories"]
    },
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "terms": {
                    "categoryValues.keyword": ["5aeb3714-6599-461c-9644-c3dfe12da513", "db87a0e5-2b67-430c-8c6b-5dac5ebe1883"]
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    "highlight": {
        "fields": {
            "content": {}
        }
    },
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "categories": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "categoryValues.keyword",
                "size": 642
            }
        }
    }
   }
```

the size of aggs is big because we need to get all

As you can see I am searching for two keyword values

```
["5aeb3714-6599-461c-9644-c3dfe12da513", "db87a0e5-2b67-430c-8c6b-5dac5ebe1883"]
```

My results however return 3

```
   {
    "took": 0,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 2,
        "max_score": 0,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "categories": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [{
                "key": "3b93a7af-282b-4689-8f23-884891a9cd26",
                "doc_count": 2
            }, {
                "key": "5aeb3714-6599-461c-9644-c3dfe12da513",
                "doc_count": 1
            }, {
                "key": "db87a0e5-2b67-430c-8c6b-5dac5ebe1883",
                "doc_count": 1
            }]
        }
    }
   }
```

What is that key "3b93a7af-282b-4689-8f23-884891a9cd26" Doing there?
Is this an ElasticSearch bug? Or have I done my query wrong - I don't see how I could have done my query wrong since keyword searches should be exact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `categoryValues` can be an array, all the values of the array are aggregated, which is why you get `3b93a7af-282b-4689-8f23-884891a9cd26` as well. Looking at the `doc_count` (2), it probably is contained in both matching documents.

What you can do is to [filter the values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_with_exact_values_2) you want to see in the aggregation response:

```
"aggs": {
    "categories": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "categoryValues.keyword",
            "size": 642,
            "include": ["5aeb3714-6599-461c-9644-c3dfe12da513", "db87a0e5-2b67-430c-8c6b-5dac5ebe1883"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I was so focused on the query I didn't think about the aggregation!